# How to send and read SMS using GSM Modem with at commands

Tags: c#

I want send and receive sms using gsm modem with AT commands.I used as sample https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/38705/Send-and-Read-SMS-through-a-GSM-Modem-using-AT-Com?
but this program send message <> and sometimes not send message.

```
port.PortName = "COM6";
port.ReadTimeout = 2000;
port.Open();
port.Write("AT" + "\r");
// Thread.Sleep(1500);
port.Write("AT+CMGF=1" + "\r");
Thread.Sleep(1500);
// port.Write("AT+CSCS=\"PCCP437\"" + "\r");
// Thread.Sleep(100);
port.Write("AT+CMGS=\"" + txtSIM.Text.Trim() + "\"" + "\r\n");
Thread.Sleep(1500);
port.Write(txtMessage.Text.Trim() + "\x1A");
MessageBox.Show("Message successfully");
```

Comment: Back in the Dark Ages when I did some of this 'at' programming I found nothing would work unless I added delays between the activities (because the whole at thing was originally put in place to be used by humans, not automated systems) - thus I'd be tempted to add a little delay between the open and the write. Also, you don't seem to be checking for exceptions, which is even more essential than usual in this sort of low level comms programming. Good luck!

Comment: Why are you have different terminators and end of line?  You are writing to a serial port and it should always work.  If it is not working it is due to the line terminators being wrong.  You also do not need sleep.